# Re-render flat-list in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-typescript

I have an empty array that I pass to my `flat-list`.
I also use `useEffect` to fetch data from the server and update the list.
However, after setting the new state of the array with the data, the `flat-list` is not re-rendered.

```
const [listData, setlistData] = React.useState<Transaction[]>([])
const [dataUpdated, setDataUpdated] = React.useState<boolean>(false)

React.useEffect(() => {

    if(route.params.showAllData)
    {
        fetchTransactions(1, TRANSACTION_PAGE_SIZE, 1)
            .then((res: Transaction) => {
                console.log(`TransactionsScreen: userEffect [] => fetched ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
                setlistData(prevState => ({...prevState, ...res}));
                setDataUpdated(true)
            })
            .catch(err => {

                //TODO: handle error scenerio
                ToastAndroid.show(`Failed to fetch transacrions`, ToastAndroid.SHORT)
                
            })
    }}, [])    

<FlatList
     data={listData}
     renderItem={item => _renderItem(item)}
     ItemSeparatorComponent={TransactionListSeparator}
     extraData={dataUpdated} // extraData={listData <--- didn't work either}
     keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}/>
```

I tried to add the data array as `extraData` value but it didn't work, I also tried to add another boolean notifying that the data was updated but it didn't work either.

How can re-render the `flat-list` correctly?

Comment: Your useEffect has an empty depency, check if your `listData` is getting updated or not by console logging it

Comment: @GayatriDipali, it does get changed, I have another `useEffect` (which I didn't post here) on listData, which logs the updated values.

Comment: Can you try pass key with state of the current time ?

Answer (score 4):

You can force flatlist to rerender by passing the updated list as an extraData prop, i.e `extraData={listData}`. However, when using functional components a common mistake is passing the same instance of the list data as the prop. This will not trigger a rerender even if the content in the list or the length of the list has changed. FlatList sees this as the same and will not rerender.
To trigger a rerender you have to create an entirely new instance of the list.

Egs:

```
//This update will NOT trigger a rerender
const copy = listData;
copy.push(something)
setListData(copy)

////////
<FlatList extraData={listData}
.....
/>
```

```
//This WILL trigger a rerender
const copy = [...listData]
copy.push(something)
setListData(copy)

////////
<FlatList extraData={listData}
.....
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem this way :

```
useEffect(() => {
    setDataUpdated(!dataUpdated);
  }, [listData]);
```

**NOTE :**
Your updating the `dataUpdated` to true directly. I do not recommend this, do it this way instead : `setDataUpdated(!dataUpdated)`

Plus ensure that **all elements of the `FlatList` have a unique key**, if not it will not re-render at any cost

Comment: I tried your approach and added `dataUpdated` as `extraData` but the list is not re-rendering.. :/

Comment: Sorry I had given a wrong dependency, fixed it now!

Comment: still doesn't work... I log the `listData` in the useEffect, and it does have values. However my `_renderItem()` function never gets called

Comment: Can you create a snack and drop the link

Answer (score 1):

Try this, make sure you are returning your child component and giving dependency array with useEffect upon which chnage you want to re-render your component

```js
const [listData, setlistData] = React.useState<Transaction[]>([])
const [dataUpdated, setDataUpdated] = React.useState<boolean>(false)

React.useEffect(() => {

    if(route.params.showAllData)
    {
        fetchTransactions(1, TRANSACTION_PAGE_SIZE, 1)
            .then((res: Transaction) => {
                console.log(`TransactionsScreen: userEffect [] => fetched                  ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
                setlistData(prevState => ({...prevState, ...res}));
                setDataUpdated(true)
            })
            .catch(err => {

                //TODO: handle error scenerio
                ToastAndroid.show(`Failed to fetch transacrions`,                              ToastAndroid.SHORT)
                
            })
    }}, [listData])  
    
    return (

  <FlatList
     data={listData}
     renderItem={item => _renderItem(item)}
     ItemSeparatorComponent={TransactionListSeparator}
     extraData={dataUpdated} // extraData={listData <--- didn't work either}
     keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}/>
     
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't spread the array as you did. For example, if you have two arrays.

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
```

And spread them like:

```
const arr3 = { ...arr1, ...arr2 };
```

The result will be:

```
{ 0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6 }
```

Change curly braces to the square.

```
setlistData(prevState => ([...prevState, ...res]));
```

Since your `FlatList` expects data to be an array, not an object.